# Error setting socket options using rest template and eureka

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

I'm trying to use eureka, rest template and @LoadBalanced annotation in order to communicate between A and B microservices.

Without Eureka, I can communicate in a proper way.

In destiny (B) microservices I'm getting:

```
2022-12-06 22:30:26.634 ERROR 6352 --- [o-8081-Acceptor] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint   : Error setting socket options

java.net.SocketException: Invalid argument
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.setIntOption0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.setSocketOption(Net.java:455) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.setSocketOption(Net.java:393) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.setOption(SocketChannelImpl.java:280) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.setIntOption(SocketAdaptor.java:247) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketAdaptor.setSoLinger(SocketAdaptor.java:285) ~[na:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProperties.setProperties(SocketProperties.java:219) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.setSocketOptions(NioEndpoint.java:495) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.setSocketOptions(NioEndpoint.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor.run(Acceptor.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.55.jar:9.0.55]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

A (Rest template call):

```
  String s= restTemplate.getForObject(
                "http://FRAUD/api/v1/fraud-check/test",
                String.class
  );

 @LoadBalanced
 @Bean
 public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
     return new RestTemplate();
 }
```

B (Rest controller):

```
@GetMapping("/test")
public String testCall() {
   return "ok";
}
```

Using MacoS MOnterrey 12.6, JDK 17, Spring boot 2.5.7 and Spring Cloud 2020.0.3. Tried to update to JDK 19, 2.6.1 and 2021.0.5 and got same errors. I also tried to use OpenFEIGN instead of RestTemplate.

Any ideas how to debug?

Comment: Have you already tried to inject a LoadBalancerClient  like this:
'public RestTemplate restTemplate(LoadBalancerClient loadBalancerClient) {
    return new RestTemplate();
}'?

Comment: It is also possible that your eureka configuration is not setup properly

Comment: @3r1c yes! I also tried to change Rest Template to OpenFeign and got same errors. I sent my project to another person that compiled and executed without any problems. It seems that could be some config into my notebook.